# Load data into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm doing now normal data loading into my `tableview` as you can see here in my **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`**, StopAndCheckQuestions is a generated class from core data.

HowI load my Data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CoreDataHelper * helper = [CoreDataHelper getCDHelper];
    FirstQuestions =[helper fetchEntitiesForClass:[StopAndCheckQuestions class] withPredicate:nil];
}



   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FirstQuestionCell";
    QuestionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell = [[QuestionCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    StopAndCheckQuestions *questions = [FirstQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblQuestion.text = questions.question;
    return cell;
```

Nothing special.
But now I want to load data that depends on the `foreign key` , this means I want all data where the `foreign key(`titleId) is 1

Can someone please help me and provide me maybe with a sample or something else

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Comment: You mean without updating NSFetchResultController ??

Comment: can you give a snapshot of your coreData model? would like to check if I understand your structure (best in tree/graph mode or relevant entities in table mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NSPredicate** for this purpose

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"KEY ==%i ", 1];
    NSArray *res = [FirstQuestions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't have a property in core data that is my foreign key , Do I need to add this ? , is there no other way .. ?

Comment: you mean you dont have titleId in StopAndCheckQuestions?

Comment: yes this is what I mean I have just the relation to the StopAndCheckTitle in CoreData

Comment: y u didnt add this in ur StopAndCheckQuestions? just add it in your table. thats the simplest solution for this problem

Comment: no I did not add titleId to StopAndCheckQuestions , but is it not possible to access the relation ?